An integrated math roadmap
Hi I am an electrical engineering undergraduate which want to learn more mathematics along the way.
I want a math roadmap consist of books which would help me to integrate different fields of applied mathematics with electrical engineering courses and some computer science courses (mostly fundamentals so I can have solid foundations for further investigation).
I appreciate if you can help to know how I can do this and whether it is possible to cover such vast areas all together.
*By integrated approach I mean that I can use what I learn to learn more from other fields.

I suggest you, see this article How to ask a good question
